# Override all binary operators (or other way to respect physics dimensions) in python?

Tags: python, overriding, binary-operators

I'm building classes inherited from float to respect a dimension in some chemical calculations. e.g.:

```
class volume(float):
  def __init__(self, value):
    float._init_(value)
```

Now my goal is:

1. to raise an error whenever + or - is used between a normal float and an instance of volume
2. return an instance of volume, whenever + or - is used between two instances of volume
3. return an instance of volume, whenever * is used (from both sides) and / is used (from left)
4. raise an error when / is used from left
5. return a float whenever two instances of volume are divided.

Right now, I'm going to override all these four operators, from left and right (e.g. _*add*_ and _*radd*_);

```
err='Only objects of type volume can be added or subtracted together'
def __add__(self,volume2):
  if isinstance(volume2,volume): return volume(float(self)+volume2)
  else: raise TypeError(err)
def __radd__(self,volume2):
  if isinstance(volume2,volume): return volume(float(self)+volume2)
  else: raise TypeError(err)
```

Is there any easier way to access all of them, or at least an expression to include both left and right uses of the operator?

Comment: Please provide the "standard" code of `__add__` and `__radd__` implementation and a sample of what you want to achieve, it is not really clear what you want. If I got it correctly, yes, there are ways, but with a tradeoff for code clarity (IMO)

Comment: If you don't want your volume class to be usable anywhere a `float` could be used, that defeats the purpose of inheritance.

Comment: So you are after reducing code duplication (the `__add__` and `__radd__` have the same code)?

Comment: `float._init_(value)` - what is this line? `float.__init__(value)` (with double underscore)? Also calling `self+volume2` inside `__add__` expectedly results in `RecursionError`...

Comment: @JanStránský; done, thanks for the remark.

@Abion47; It is mostly being treated as a float. The binary operations are supposed to work the same way, but I want the result to stay in the same type (or raise an error occasionally).

Comment: @JanStránský Yes, exactly (reducing code duplication). fixed the RecursionError; by typecasting self to float..

Comment: @ZahraM `RecursionError` fixed, but then you modify the code to the exact form you want to avoid (float + volume) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this question is primarily about avoiding code duplication.  Regarding the multiply and divide cases, you have slightly different functionality and may have to write separate methods explicitly, but for the addition and subtraction related methods, the following technique would work.  It is essentially monkey-patching the class, and it is okay to do this, although you should not attempt similarly to monkey-patch *instances* in Python 3.

I have called the class `Volume` with capital V in accordance with convention.

```
class Volume(float):
  pass

def _make_wrapper(name):
    def wrapper(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Volume):
            raise ValueError
        return Volume(getattr(float, name)(self, other))
    setattr(Volume, name, wrapper)

for _method in ('__add__', '__radd__', 
                '__sub__', '__rsub__',):                    
    _make_wrapper(_method)
```

The equivalent explicit method in these cases looks like the following, so adapt as required for the multiply / divide cases, but note the explicit use of `float.__add__(self, other)` rather than `self + other` as the question suggests that you intended to use (where the question mentions `volume(self+volume2)`), which would lead to infinite recursion.

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Volume):
            raise ValueError
        return Volume(float.__add__(self, other))
```

Regarding the `__init__`, I have now removed it above, because if all it does is call `float.__init__`, then it is not necessary to define it at all (let it simply inherit `__init__` from the base class).  If you want to have an `__init__` method in order to initialise something *else*, then yes you will *also* need to include the explicit call to `float.__init__` as you do in the question (although note the double underscores -- in the question you are trying to call `float._init_`).

Comment: I tried this, it does not raise any errors, but the sum of two volume instances still has the type float (not type volume, as I expect)

Comment: @Zara It's working for me. Tells me `<class '__main__.Volume'>`

Comment: Yes, my bad, I was still calling lower case volume:)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`metaclass` is a the way to control how `class` are constructed.

You can use `metaclasses` to overload all the math oeprators like this:

```py
err='Only objects of type volume can be added or subtracted together'

class OverLoadMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta,name,bases,dct):
        # this is the operation you want to use instead of default add or subtract.
        def op(self,volume2):
            if isinstance(volume2,Volume): 
                return Volume(float.__add__(self,volume2))
            else:
                raise TypeError(err)
        # you can overload whatever method you want here
        for method in ('__add__','__radd__','__sub__'):
            dct[method] = op
        
        return super(OverLoadMeta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)


class Volume(float,metaclass=OverLoadMeta):
    ""


# you can use it like this:
a = Volume(1)
b = Volume(2)

c = a+b
print(c.__class__)
# class will be <class '__main__.Volume'>

a + 1
# raise TypeError: Only objects of type volume can be added or subtracted together
```